# Class extending KeyListener not responding to key presses

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, setfocus

Sorry about its being a duplicate - I was in a hurry when I wrote this, and didn't have time to check. Though I suppose it would have been faster, now that I think about it...

---

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java KeyListener for JFrame is being unresponsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286727/java-keylistener-for-jframe-is-being-unresponsive)

I have been writing an app and am trying to make hotkeys. I decided to use `KeyListener`, as it is all I know as of yet. However, the class is not responding to key presses. How would I fix this bug? If there is an alternative to `KeyListener` that will do the same thing, please let me know and preferably provide an example of how it would work.

#### Main class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import panels.TabBar;

public class __mn implements KeyListener {
    static JFrame disp = new JFrame("dat app");

    static TabBar tabs = new TabBar();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        disp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        disp.add(tabs, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        disp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        disp.setSize(TabBar.PREF_WIDTH, 500);
        disp.setResizable(false);
        disp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        disp.addKeyListener(new __mn());
        disp.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
    }

    //Unused
    @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
    } 
    @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
    }
}
```

#### TabBar class

```
package panels;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245148-java-key-binding-tutorial-and-demo-program/

public class TabBar extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int NONE = -1;
    public static final int INBOX = 0;
    public static final int SEND_MSG = 1;
    public static final int PRIVATE_CHAT = 2;
    public static final int FEEDBACK = 3;

    public static final int PREF_WIDTH = 425;

    private static final String[] tabNames = {"Inbox", "Send a message", "Private chat", "Feedback"};

    private static final JButton btnInbox = new JButton(tabNames[INBOX]);
    private static final JButton btnSendMSG = new JButton(tabNames[SEND_MSG]);
    private static final JButton btnPrivChat = new JButton(tabNames[PRIVATE_CHAT]);
    private static final JButton btnFeedback = new JButton(tabNames[FEEDBACK]);

    public int currentTab = -1;

    public TabBar() {
        this(new FlowLayout());
    }

    public TabBar(LayoutManager layout) {
        super(layout);

        add(btnInbox);
        add(btnSendMSG);
        add(btnPrivChat);
        add(btnFeedback);

        btnInbox.addActionListener(this);
        btnSendMSG.addActionListener(this);
        btnPrivChat.addActionListener(this);
        btnFeedback.addActionListener(this);

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
        if (e.getSource() == btnInbox)
            currentTab = INBOX;
        else if (e.getSource() == btnSendMSG)
            currentTab = SEND_MSG;
        else if (e.getSource() == btnPrivChat)
            currentTab = PRIVATE_CHAT;
        else if (e.getSource() == btnFeedback)
            currentTab = FEEDBACK;
        else currentTab = NONE;
    }

    public void hotkeyPressed(char pressed) {
        pressed = Character.toLowerCase(pressed);
        System.out.println("Hotkey pressed: " + pressed);
        switch (pressed) {
        case 'i':
            setTab(INBOX);
            break;
        case 's':
            setTab(SEND_MSG);
            break;
        case 'p':
            setTab(PRIVATE_CHAT);
            break;
        case 'f':
            setTab(FEEDBACK);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void setTab(int tab) {
        System.out.println("Somthing pressed! tab=" + tab);
        currentTab = tab;
        switch (tab) {
        case INBOX:
            btnInbox.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Feel free to edit code out if you feel it is unnecessary." - *you* should do this.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console ? Where exactly is the `hotkeyPressed` method called ? Which keys are you trying to test?

Comment: Quick answer, to be sure.. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @LeeMeador Mind just making that into an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: You can use [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14122382/1057230). KeyListeners are way too low level from Swing's perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I fix this bug?

Not really a bug as much as incompatiblity.

> If there is an alternative to KeyListener that will do the same thing,
>   please let me know and preferably provide an example of how it would
>   work.

Dont use `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` for Swing components as there is focus issues, which can be gotten around by calling `requestFocusInWindow()` on the component after its visible to make sure it has focus and of course `setFoucsable(true);` must be called if component is not *focusable* like a `JLabel`.

Swing components should use [`KeyBinding`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which overcomes the above mentioned problems by automatically calling `setFocusable(true)` on the component to which `KeyBinding` is added etc.

Here is a small example:

```
void addKeyBinding(JComponent jc) {
        jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "A pressed");
        jc.getActionMap().put("esc pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("A pressed");
            }
        });

        jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "A released");
        jc.getActionMap().put("A released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("A released");
            }
        });
}
```

you would call this method with the instance of the `JComponent` i.e `JPanel` etc that you want to add the `Keybinding` too:

```
JPanel p=new JPanel();

addKeyBinding(p);
```

**Other suggestions on code:**

- Always create Swing components on `Event Dispatch Thread` via `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block
- Dont implement an `Listener` like `ActionListener` on the class itself unless this class will be used as a `Listener` **only**, or you want to expose the implementing classes/`Listeners` methods to other classes.

Comment: +1 for key bindings; until [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13999506/230513) I'd [argued](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999691/230513) that games might be an exception, but I was [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001011/230513). :-)

Comment: @trashgod +1 hehe Keybindings is the one and only guess we just needed to learn why to adopt em and after many problems with KeyListeners in my games I found KeyBindings a more typing initially but it pays off in the end

Comment: This seems perfect for what I have in mind. Thanks! But is there a reason to make that a separate method and not put the addition of key bindings in the constructor?

Comment: @NickHartley no just for readabilty of code

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Then I'll probably add an array as an argument so that it's more easily customized. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... I am using Java 6 and this doesn't seem to work. Is there any other things I need to think about? The source code now is identical to above, but I added three more bindings and changed the keys and masks. If you need the source code, just copy/paste what you have above three times and change the mask to `KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK`. Thanks!

Comment: @NickHartley Does my original work? Yes? well than your additions are the problem... most likely you should change the text from *A released* or *A pressed* to something else (thats unique for that keybinding or else it will overwrite previous KeyBinding with that `string`,  you cant say because you copied and pasted and added 3 more methods it doesnt work, thus  your code is not the problem, id need the source code there is many things that could go wrong....

Comment: Actually, I just tested the original, and it doesn't work. But I figured out the problem.. I was trying to use a JFrame, not a JPanel. I misead. XD

Comment: Alos, forgive me if I didn't say this clearly enough, but when I said `I changed the keys` I meant that I changed not just the key *presses* but the String key used in the ActionMap and InputMap. Either way, it was a stupid error on my part that caused the glitch, so it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The JFrame consists of many different components and, as such, is not inheirently focusable. Without focus, it can not receive key events. There are a lot of solutions to this. I'm only going to suggest this one:

[Unresponsive KeyListener for JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286727/java-keylistener-for-jframe-is-being-unresponsive)

And I'll suggest you google "keylistener on jframe java" to find some more info. Like I said, there are a lot of ways to tackle this problem.

Comment: This is not best practice, Keybindings should be used for Swing components

Comment: +1 for a good explanation, but @DavidKroukamp is right about suggesting [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Key bindings is suggested in either the linked article or one of the top few answers from the Google search. I saw no reason to repeat everything said there. Glad @DavidKroukamp can suggest where Nick can best focus his reading.