# Shortcut Key outside of Form for Java Application

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have an application thats, example of a auto typer.

I want to have shortcut key to trigger an event, so when I press the shortcut key anywhere without focusing on the application it still call the event.

For example, f12 is my shortcut key, when i press f12, it will trigger the event, this will happen when I'm focus the form or not.

Is that possible in Java Application?.

Comment: Do you want a system-wide shortcut (so even if your application is minimized, it still works) or just an applicatoin shortcut? The first is impossible in pure Java, while the second is very easy using Swing KeyBindings.

Comment: Yes @GuillaumePolet, thats wat i wanted :)...

Comment: Im trying to look into KeyBindings atm, all the info im able to find are keybindings that work when ur focus your application, do u have any example that work for what i desire? :)..thanks in advance if u do.

Comment: The comment was that you can't do this in Java when the application doesn't have focus. You need to use JNI or JNA and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Apart from [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/), you can also look into, [JNativeHooks](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/). You might also find this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14118734/1057230) useful :-)

Comment: @zBaoAnhLe What do you want? I am asking "do you want this or that?" and you answer me "Yes". I still don't know which one you want.

Comment: 1) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet i want a system-wide shortcut (so even if your application is minimized, it still works)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Look into the Swing `Action`. There is more info here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: Action and Key Bindings are always good, but the application must have focus for this to work.