# Java - Is it possible to detect when Mouse Button Four or KeyPress anytime?

Tags: java, swing

So I have been trying to figure out some things with Java. I have the click event trigger and print "SUPSUP" in the program when the JFrame window pops up. But I was wondering is there a way to set up the app where if I press button 4 outside the JFrame window the "SUPSUP" will still be printed? I mean I want to have a listener in java in general not tied to the JFrame Components, I wouldn't mind if I needed to use a key listener either. I'm trying to build a program that will do certain things on the screen every time I click on button 4, but I can't be able to click on the blue JFrame thanks.

So Far I have this code.

```
public class CriticalMassWizard implements MouseListener
{
private static CriticalMassWizard instance = null;
private static Robot robot;
private static boolean triggerSpam;
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tester");

// Singleton
public static CriticalMassWizard getInstance() 
{
   if(instance == null) {

      instance = new CriticalMassWizard();
      instance.setUpFrame();

      try {
        robot = new Robot();
      } catch (AWTException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   return instance;
}

private void setUpFrame()
{
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addMouseListener(this);
}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getButton() == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("SUPSUP");
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Comment: Not through the native Java libraries, you will need a JNI/JNA solution

Comment: @ExcelledProducts I'm trying to implement the code there but I keep running into a UnsatisfiedLinkError would you know how to solve that?

Comment: you have not linking the dll library.

Comment: -Djava.library.path="C:/absolute/path/to/mousehook.dll, C:/absolute/path/to/keyboardhook.dll"

Comment: @MichaelChoi: Please have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14118734/1057230), hopefully it might be able to help somewhat :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now this is related to `FocusListeners` and the focus that is set at a point in time at whatever `JFrame` you are on. It might be possible if you have multiple JFrame's and you click on one of them to output something on another, but if you click on your desktop,for eg, then this cannot be accomplished through native Java Libraries.