# Send native events

Tags: java, windows, swing, events

I am attempting to send native MouseEvents and KeyEvents to a java application.

I've figured out how to do it in AWT, like this:

```
KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent(j, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 1, 0, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 'k');
j.requestFocus();
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(k);
```

Where j is your component.

The thing is though, this only works on Java/AWT components. I'm attempting to emulate a mouse press or key press in DJ Native Browser, but it doesn't work here, possibly because this browser doesn't use AWT. Is there a way I can send a native windows event to the application without affecting my actual keyboard and mouse? Obviously `awt.Robot` is the obvious answer but it DOES affect the windows mouse and keyboard.

If the way to do it is operating-system dependent, that is OK. As long as it works on windows 64 bit, there is no issue with that.

Another possibility would be a java swing browser that runs on AWT, but I have yet to find a working, up-to-date browser besides DJNative, let alone one that runs on AWT.

Suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you're still on the wrong side of the fence. That is, the SystemEventQueue is a Java based event queue, which is used to take system events from the OS and translate them to Java events. You may need to investigate a JNI/JNA solution to inject new events into the OS level event queue. There a number of issues related to doing this (needing the window handle for the target window for example), but it's probably the best choice you've got left....

Comment: @MadProgrammer , perhaps I should try to find an AWT browser then? In standard swing components, the above code works fine and I can emulate keypresses and mouse actions fine.

Comment: I don't know of any standard component that is up to the modern WebKit implementations

Comment: Do some research into WebKit, which what most of the modern browsers are now built upon. Have a look at http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp, https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ and maybe https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2008/05/introducing_jwe.html but it seems to be dated

Comment: @Nathan: Please have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14118734/1057230), might be, it will be of some importance in your endeavour :-)

Comment: Thank you both of you, your comments gave me a few leads for where to look, back go research!